# multitype textread in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am working with a matlab project. And I have a text file like this

```
AGE 1   1
SEX 2   2
NOP 3   0
SES 0   5
PDD 6   6
ACD 0   0
UDC 8   3
```

and i want to create a variable from this tab delimited file using textread like the sample below.

```
x= 

    'AGE'   1   1
    'SEX'   2   0
    'NOp'   3   3
    'SES'   0   5
    'PDD'   6   6
    'ACD'   0   0
    'UDC'   8   3
```

how can i do it? I tried many things but couldn't manage to find a solution please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
Filename = 'testfile.txt';    
fid = fopen(Filename);
Output = textscan(fid, '%s %d %d', 'delimiter', ' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

Then you'll have:

```
Output = 
{7x1 cell}    [7x1 int32]    [7x1 int32]

Output{1} =
'AGE'
'SEX'
'NOP'
'SES'
'PDD'
'ACD'
'UDC'

Output{2} =
       1
       2
       3
       0
       6
       0
       8

Output{3} =
       1
       2
       0
       5
       6
       0
       3
```

Then to expand the cell arrays elements, so that each element can be addressed directly:

```
x = [ Output{1}, num2cell(Output{2}), num2cell(Output{3}) ]

x = 
'AGE'    [1]    [1]
'SEX'    [2]    [2]
'NOP'    [3]    [0]
'SES'    [0]    [5]
'PDD'    [6]    [6]
'ACD'    [0]    [0]
'UDC'    [8]    [3]
```

And then you can address the elements directly:

```
x(1,1) = 
'AGE'

x(5,2) =
[6]
```

Comment: thank you it worked but how will i grab any cell value from this... for example i want to get (1,1) cell value how can i reach "AGE" string...

Comment: @OzgurEffe Check the edited answer. `x(1,1)` returns `'AGE'`.

Comment: is there any way of assigning all first column cell values to a new variable name like newvar_AGE=1 newvar_SEX=2 newvar_NOP = 3 ?

Comment: Creating so many similar variables is unnecessary complication and makes data handling difficult (at least without the use of `eval`). It's better to create a struct array: `rowheadings = x(:,1);` `xStruct = cell2struct(x(:,2), rowheadings);`. And then `xStruct.AGE` gives you `1`, `xStruct.NOP` gives `3` and so on.